# The "fact" whether you win or not?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am looking for a noun that could be used in this sentence to better describe the situation and make it sound more clear:

The **"fact"** whether you win or lose this game has only minor effect on your mood.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think that the noun "fact" is not used properly here because what is decribed above is not really a fact. But what is it then? A state, situation, reality? Is there any better expression?

Comment: If you need a term, consider "the outcome of the game".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose "The fact" and anything else you might write.  It's deadwood.  Instead, succinctly write:

> "Whether you win or lose  this game has only a minor effect on your mood."

By the way, without knowing context, I can't say for sure, but it may behoove you to change "has" for "will have."

Comment: The context is presenting outcomes of testing, so the "has" is correct here.
Does it also sound perfectly fine like this?:
"In conclusion, whether you win or lose has only minor effect..."

Comment: @Riko :  That's fine, but like I showed in my example, you need the article "a" before "minor."  You may semantically get away with saying "has little effect" sans article, but then you wouldn't use "only."  If you use "only" and "minor," you would say, "has only *a* minor effect."